# Why 0.33... is the only expression of 1/3?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

I am an undergraduate math student who loves mathematics very much, and I am confused by a math problem.

Given $1/3$, we know that $0.33...$ (there are infinite $3$s) is the decimal expression. But how can we prove that it is the only decimal expression of $1/3$?

Sorry for my mistakes for my wrong math typing and not good English. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Suppose there's another expression $0.a1,a2,a3,...$ look at the first $n$ such that $a_n\not = 3$. If $a_n>3$ show that this new expression is necessarily greater than $1/3$ and if $a_n<3$ it is necessarily smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! By the way, can I use this one as a strict proof?

Comment: @DietrichBrude Except for trailing lines, e.g. $\frac12=0.\dot{5}=0.4\dot{9}$.

Comment: What is written as 0.333333..... is a infinite geometric progression with common ratio 0.1. so prove the sum of the infinite gp  and i think you might be done

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271118/characterization-of-non-unique-decimal-expansions might be of interest.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, that question is asking for a proof that $0.333\ldots$ is *a* decimal representation for $1/3$. This question is asking for a proof that it is the *only* decimal representation.

Comment: @J.G. That should have been $0.5\dot{0}$, not $0.\dot{5}$.

Comment: @Wojowu Sorry, yes, or I could have avoided the dot altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

===== new answer ====

Thought experiment:

Lets suppose we are converting $x$ to decimals and we have gotten to the $k$th position and so for we have $M= a_0.a_1a_2...a_{k-1}$ and we want to figure what value to put down for $a_k$.

Question:  what is $x - M$?

Case 1:   If $x - M < 0$ or $x < M$ we have f###ed up and we'll never get back on track.  Every decimal we write down will be non-negative and our final result will be too big.

Case 2:  If $x - M = 0$ we have no choice.  We can't add anything more.  All the remaining $a_j$ will have to be $0$s.

Case 3: If $x - M > 10^{-k+ 1} = 10*10^{-k}$.  Well, again we're effed up.  All the remaining decimals can be at most $9$ and $9*10^{-k} + 9*10^{-k-1} + .... \le 10*10^{-k} = 10^{-k+1}$.  (Note: equality can hold as a limit.)

Case 4: If $x-M = 10^{-k+1}$ we have no choice.  All the remaining decimals can be at most $9$ and $9*10^{-k} + 9*10^{-k-1} + .... \le 10*10^{-k} = 10^{-k+1}$ and we *need* then to add to $10^{-k+1}$.  That's only possible if we use all $9$s from here on out.

The remaining options leaves us with $0 < x-M < 10*10^{-k}$.  That means there is an integer $b: 0\le b <10$ so that $b*10^{-k} \le x-M < (b+1)*10^{-k}$.  What value do we choose for $a_k$.

Case 5: $x-M = b*10^{-k}$ *exactly*.

Option 1:  $a_k>  b$.  That's out.  That would put us in Case 1) when we try to figure out $a_{k+1}$.

Option 2: $a_k = b$.  That's good.  And that puts us in Case 2) when we try to figure out $a_{k+1}$.

Option 3: $a_k = b-1$.  That's... acceptable.  But that will put us in Case 4) when we try to figure out $a_{k+1}$.

Option 4: $a_k < b-1$. That's out.  That would put us in Case 3) when we try to figure out $a_{k+1}$.

Case 6: $b*10^{-k} < x-M < (b+1)*10^{-k}$.

Option 1: $a_k > b$ is still out as it will put us in Case 1.

Option 2: $a_k = b$ is good.  That will put at Case 5) or 6) when we try to figure ot $a_{k+1}$.

Option 3: $a_k \le b-1$.  No longer acceptable.  That will put us in Case 3) when we try to figure out $a_{k+1}$.

....

So Our Conclusion:

In determining decimals we never have any choice unless we come to a Case 5: in which case we have a choice to terminate and end with an infinite number of zeros, or to drop by $1$ and end with an infinite number of $9$.  Otherwise we never have any choice and we have an infinite non-terminating decimal.

It's easy to see that $\frac 13$ never yields a case 5:  Read my old answer for an explanation.

==== old answer ===

Consider these rules for *writing* a decimal from a value $x$ (assuming we had some way of knowing exactly how big $x$ was):

There is a unique integer $a_0$ so that $a_0 \le x < a_0+1$. We'll take that for granted.  We actually have to prove it but... let's assume it for now.

If $x = a_0$ we are done.  If not we start with $n$ and we have to express $x_1 = x - a_0; 0 < x_1 < 1$ as a decimal.

As $0 < x_1 < 1$, if we divide $[0, 1)$ into ten intervals $[0, \frac 1{10}), [\frac 1{10}, \frac 2{10})$ ..... $[\frac 9{10}, 1)$ and $x_1$ can only lie in one of these.  Or to put it in other words there is a unique $a_1\in \{0,1,2,....,9\}$ so that $\frac {a_1}{10} \le x_1 < \frac {a_1+1}{10}$. We write down that as $a_0.a_1$ which means $a_0 +\frac {a_1}{10}$ and that's the start of our decimal.

If $x_1 = \frac {a_1}{10}$ we are done.  But if $\frac {a_1}{10} < x_1 < \frac {a_1}{10}$ we let $x_2 = x_1 - \frac {a_1}{10}$.  That means $0 < x_1 < \frac 1{10}$.  We do the same thing we did above; we divide the segment into ten pieces and find $a_2$ so that $\frac {a_2}{100} \le x_2 < \frac {a_2+1}{100}$.

And we do this forever.

We can show by induction that for $x = \frac 13$ this will never end and that each $a_i$ is distinctly determined to be $3$.

Base case: $0 < \frac 13< 1$ so $n = 0$. And $\frac 3{10} < \frac 13 < \frac 4{10} \iff \frac 9{10}< 1 < \frac {12}{10}$ which it is so $a_1 = 3$ and $x_1 = \frac 13 - \frac 3{10} = \frac {10}{30} - \frac 9{20} = \frac 1{30}$.

Induction case assume $a_k = 3$ and $x_k = \frac 1{3*10^k}$.  Then we wish to show $a_{k+1}= 3$ and $x_{k+1} = \frac 1{3*10^{k+1}}$.

Well, that's done the exact same way.

$\frac 3{10^{k+1}} < \frac 1{3*10^{k}} < \frac 4{10^{k+1}} \iff \frac 9{10^{k+1}} < \frac {10}{3*10^{k+1}} < \frac {12}{10^{k+1}}$ which is does.  So $a_{k+1} = 3$.

So $x_{k+1} = \frac 1{3*10^{k}}-\frac 3{10^{k+1}} = \frac {10}{3*10^{k+1}} - \frac 9{3*10^{k+1}} = \frac 1{3*10^{k+1}}$.

So that's it.  By following those rules making decimals.  $0.33333....$ is the only decimal that can be made from $\frac 13$.

........

But wait a minute!  By those rules, $1 = 1$ is only decimal that can be made from $1$ and $0.99999999.....$ can never be made.  But we know it can.  What gives?

Well, those were rules for *writing* decimals; not for *reading* decimals.  For reading decimals we can read $0.99999.......$ as $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 9{10^k} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 9{10^k}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (1-\frac 1{10^{n+1}}) = 1-\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{10^{n+1}} = 1$.

So why can't there be another decimal that can be read to be $\frac 13$?

Well,

Claim:  The only values of decimals that have two readings: $a_0.a_1a_2a_3......$ and $b_0.b_1b_2b_3......$ are where there is some point $k$ where $a_i = b_i$ for all $i < k$.  $b_k = a_k -1$ and $a_j = 0; b_j = 9$ for all $j > k$.

In other words.  Terminating decimals that end with an infinite number of zeros can be written as a decimal that ends with an infinite number of nines.

Pf:  Let $k$ be the first term where $a_k \ne b_k$.  Without loss of generality lets assume $b_k < a_k$.  $0.0000......00b_{k+1}b_{k+2}..... \le 0.00000......0099999.... = \frac 1{10^k}$.  And $0.00.....00a_{k+1}a_{k+2} .......  \ge 0$.   Now $a_0.a_1.....a_{k-1} = b_0.b_1.....b_{k-1}$.

So $a_0.a_1.....a_{k-1} + a_k*10^{-k} + 0.00.....00a_{k+1}a_{k+2} ....... = b_0.b_1.....b_{k-1} + b_k^{-k} + 0.0000......00b_{k+1}b_{k+2}..... $ so

$a_k - b_k =10^k( 0.0000......00b_{k+1}b_{k+2}.....  - 0.00.....00a_{k+1}a_{k+2} .......) \le 1$.

But $a_k> b_k$ and $a_k$ and $b_k$ are integers so that $a_k - b_k \ge 1$.  So $a_k - b_k = 1$ and $0.00.....00a_{k+1}a_{k+2} ....... = 0$ and $0.0000......00b_{k+1}b_{k+2}..... = 1$.

But if any $a_j >0$ for $j > k$ then $0.00.....00a_{k+1}a_{k+2} .......> 0$. so thats not possible. And if any $b_j < 9$ for $j > k$ then $0.0000......00b_{k+1}b_{k+2}..... \le 0.00000......0099999....- (9-b_j)10^{-j} = \frac 1{10^k}-(9-b_j)10^{-j} < \frac 1{10^k}$ which means $a_k - b_k =10^k( 0.0000......00b_{k+1}b_{k+2}.....  - 0.00.....00a_{k+1}a_{k+2} .......) < 1$ which is impossible.

So $b_k = a_k -1$ and $a_j = 0$ for all $j > k$ and $b_j = 9$ for all $j >k$.

......

That's that.  Terminating decimals are the only decimals with two representations.  And $\frac 13$ is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $1/3<1,$ so a decimal expression for $1/3$ must be of the form

$x=0.a_1a_2a_3...a_n...=\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i10^{-i},$ where $0 \le a_i \le 9.$

As suggested by @Yanko, suppose that
for some $n,$ $a_n < 3$ but $a_i=3$ for $i\lt n$ .  Then

$3x = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 9\times 10^{-i} + 3a_n10^{-n} + 3\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty a_i10^{-i}$

$\quad\quad < 1-10^{-n+1}+7\times10^{-n}+3\times 10^{-n}=1,$

so $x<1/3$.

On the other hand, if for some $n, a_n>3$ but $a_i=3$ for $i\lt n,$

then $3x\ge\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} 9\times 10^{-i} + 12 \times 10^{-n} = 1 - 10^{-n+1} + 1.2 \times 10^{-n+1}>1,$

so $x > 1/3.$

Answer (score 1):

We're considering numbers in the interval $(0,1)$. Suppose we have two alignments
\begin{align}
a &= 0.a_1a_2\dots a_{n-1}a_n\dots \\
b &= 0.b_1b_2\dots b_{n-1}b_n\dots
\end{align}
that coincide up to the digits at place $n-1$ (with $a_0=b_0=0$) and differ in the digit at place $n$. Without loss of generality, we can assume $a_n<b_n$, so $a_n+1\le b_n$. Let
$$
c=\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{10^2}+\dots+\frac{a_{n-1}}{10^{n-1}}=
\frac{b_1}{10}+\frac{b_2}{10^2}+\dots+\frac{b_{n-1}}{10^{n-1}}
$$
The first alignment represents the number
$$
\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{a_k}{10^k}=c+\frac{a_n}{10^n}+\sum_{k>n}\frac{a_k}{10^k}
$$
With standard arguments we can see that
$$
\sum_{k>n}\frac{a_k}{10^k}\le\sum_{k>n}\frac{9}{10^k}=\frac{9}{10^{n+1}}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{1}{10^k}=\frac{9}{10^{n+1}}\frac{10}{9}=\frac{1}{10^n}
$$
Therefore
$$
a=c+\frac{a_n}{10^n}+\sum_{k>n}\frac{a_k}{10^k}\le c+\frac{a_n}{10^n}+\frac{1}{10^n}
\le c+\frac{b_n}{10^n}
\color{red}{\le} c+\frac{b_n}{10^n}+\sum_{k>n}\frac{b_k}{10^k}=b
$$
where the red $\color{red}{\le}$ can be replaced by the strict inequality $<$ *unless* $b_k=0$, for every $k>n$.

Therefore the two differing alignments may represent the same number only if the second one is terminating, in the sense that it is eventually the constant $0$. In order this to actually happen, we need also that $a_n=b_n-1$ and $a_k=9$, for every $k>n$ (prove it).

This is not the case for the decimal expansion of $1/3$, so this representation is unique.